# Вывести изображение с виртуалки на внешний дсиплей

Tags: debian, kvm, vga

Есть комп с установленным debian'ом. На нем несколько виртуальных машин. Как сделать так, чтобы на VGA выход выводился экран одной из них? Возможно ли такое?

upd: вот типа вот этого надо сделать, только для дебиана - https://habrahabr.ru/post/137327/

Comment: а куда сейчас выводит изображение программа *virt-viewer* (возможно, вы запускаете её не напрямую, а, например, из *virt-manager*-а).

Comment: выводит в хост-платформу, а как перенастроить я не знаю :( мне нужно чтобы на VGA выводился только лишь экран виртуалки

Comment: увы, понятнее ваши трудности не стали. что такое «в хост-платформу» и при чем тут тогда выход vga? я думаю, вам стоит добавить подробностей в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: наводящие вопросы: у вас два видеоадаптера и один не работает? или один видеоадаптер с двумя видеовыходами и один не работает?

Comment: кстати да, я б видюху полностью гостю отдал при такой задумке

Comment: 1 видеоадаптер, 1 видеовыход VGA. сейчас через него выводит экран debian'а, мне нужно вывести через него только экран гостевой ОС.

Comment: запускай вирт-вьювер в полном экране на том мониторе